# Deploying war file to Azure App Service not working

Tags: java, tomcat, azure-web-app-service, war, azure-app-service-plans

I'm trying to deploy a sample.war file to an Azure App Service running Windows/Tomcat 9. I'm uploading file to the wwwroot/webapps folder. The file is getting unpackaged but its not creating a subfolder named sample. I've enabled the logging but there's nothing in there that is very helpful. Any thoughts?

The sample war file I'm trying to use comes from apache tomcat page.
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/

Answer (score 0):

Please use the new WarDeploy endpoint to upload your WAR files to Azure App Service.

For more information on WarDeploy:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-WAR-files-using-wardeploy
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-zip

Also you can use the Maven plugin which will use the WarDeploy endpoint behind the scenes:

For more information on the Maven plugin:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-java
https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/tree/develop/azure-webapp-maven-plugin